# Inverted text bug - phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have this code that when phantomjs "types" it, it is inverted:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    page.sendEvent('keypress', "Hello world.\r\nThis is a test message.\r\n\"How are you doing?\"  \/\/\/\/ 1111 ^^^^ 2222\u200A\u2014\u200A\u2014 3333 !!!! 4444 &&&& 5555 %%%% 6666 ???? 7777  ???? %%%% &&&& !!!! ^^^^\u200A\u2014\u200A\u2014 **** ++++ ====\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\"\u9053\u53EF\u9053\u975E\u5E38\u9053\uFF0C\u540D\u53EF\u540D\u975E\u5E38\u540D\u3002\" and \"\u543E\u8F29\u306F\u732B\u3067\u2202\u308B\uFF08\u590F\uFF6D\uFF9A\u6F31\u2F6F\uFF09\uFF1A\u543E\u8F29\u306F\u732B ...", null, null, null, 0);
    page.evaluate(function(){});
    setTimeout(function () {
            page.render("page.png");
            phantom.exit();
        }, 10000);
}, 5000);
```

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

What could be wrong in my code that makes the *typed text* somehow inverted?

Comment: What do you mean by "inverted"? Seems normal on the scrteenshot.

Comment: @Vaviloff "Hello world" was supposed to be the first words... but what happened is that the Chinese characters are the first ones that was typed.